# Undefined method in a javascript object

Tags: javascript

Here is my problem, I have the following StatCharac object :

```
function StatCharac (initVal) {
  this.initVal = initVal;
  this.val = initVal;
  this.modifs = [];
  this.getVal = function() {
    var stat = this.val;
    for (var i =0; i < this.modifs.length; i++) {
      stat = this.modifs[i](stat);
    }
    return stat;
  }
}
```

And when I try to access to the getVal method, the console says that this method is undefined. I have already defined a method the same way in another object and everything was fine. I also have tried to use the prototype attribute of StatCharac, but it doesn't work neither...

What's wrong ?

EDIT :
When I say access to getVal it's this way :

```
console.log('message : ' + character.hp.getVal);
```

I tried to do it for other methods, and if the methods is recognised, its code is supposed to appear in the message.

Here is where I use StatCharac :

```
function Character (nameCharac, id, hp, spell, owner) {
  this.nameCharac = nameCharac;
  this.id = id;
  this.hp = new StatCharac(hp);
  this.power = new StatCharac(0);
  this.spell = spell;
  this.pos = -1;
  this.canMove = false;
  this.canPlay = false;
  this.owner = owner;
}
```

When I try to call getVal() I get the following error :

Missing error handler on 'socket'.
TypeError: Object # has no method 'getVal'
at Socket. (blabla\app.js:237:55)
...

FINAL EDIT : Ok I found where the problem was. Actually, I copy my characters from this array :

```
var dbCharacters = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 44; i ++) {
  dbCharacters[i] = new Character('PersoYolo'+(i+1), i, 100, null);
}
```

In order to clone the characters (and not only get the reference) I use this function :

```
function clone (o) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

But after a test, it appears that this function clone only the attributes of the object o, and not its method. So now I have to found how to clone a whole object in JS.

Comment: How are you "trying to access the getVal method"?  Where's that code?

Comment: Please post how you call StatCharac and how you are trying to access the property.

Comment: What is `character`? What is `character.hp`?

Comment: make sure to have done `character.hp = new StatCharac(…)` and then `character.hp.getVal()`

Comment: Well, that's not a *call* to "getVal", it's just a reference to the function itself. What *exactly* is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/3zep5kca/

Answer (score 0):

As an example:

```
function StatCharac (initVal) {
  this.initVal = initVal;
  this.val = initVal;
  this.modifs = [];
  this.getVal = function() {
    var stat = this.val;
    for (var i =0; i < this.modifs.length; i++) {
      stat = this.modifs[i](stat);
    }
    return stat;
  }
}
```

and call it like this for example:

```
var obj = new StatCharac(23)
console.log(obj.getVal())
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what's different with the version I posted ? I tried to call the function this way and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually call getVal - the code above works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function StatCharac (initVal) {
  this.initVal = initVal;
  this.val = initVal;
  this.modifs = [];
  this.getVal = function() {
    var stat = this.val;
    for (var i =0; i < this.modifs.length; i++) {
      stat = this.modifs[i](stat);
    }
    return stat;
  }
}

function Character (nameCharac, id, hp, spell, owner) {
  this.nameCharac = nameCharac;
  this.id = id;
  this.hp = new StatCharac(hp);
  this.power = new StatCharac(0);
  this.spell = spell;
  this.pos = -1;
  this.canMove = false;
  this.canPlay = false;
  this.owner = owner;
}


var character = new Character()
console.log(character.hp.getVal)
```

This is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('message: ' + {name: 'character object', hp: new StatCharac(1)}.hp.getVal)
```

Works fine.